# Why are differential equations with sinusoidal source terms easier to solve than others?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, fourier-analysis, motivation, fourier-transform

I am a software engineer trying to wrap my tiny human brain around Fourier Transforms for a project I'm currently working on. Although I will ultimately use an open source Math library to do all the heavy lifting for me, I don't like to do anything without at least having a *basic* understanding of it, so I came here.

My *understanding* is that linear differential equations with non-sinusoidal source terms are hard to solve (though I don't understand why). And so Fourier Transform helps convert these problems into several component linear differential equations **with** sinusoidal source terms, which are apparently easy to solve.

**So first, if I have misunderstood the motivation/reasoning behind the use of Fourier Transforms, please begin by correcting me!**

---

Assuming I'm more or less correct, there are a few mental blockers for me here:

- Does Fourier Transform only apply to **linear** differential equations? If so, why?
- How many smaller "component" functions (with sinusoidal source terms) does Fourier Transform produce?

Moreover, why (from a 30,000 ft view) is solving something like this (don't get hung up on the specific functional definitions, I'm just providing these as *straw men* examples):

```
L[y(t)] = 3t^2 + 4t + 8          // Non-sinusoidal source term
```

harder to solve than something like this:

```
L[y(t)] = 2sin(4*PI + t) - 20    // Sinusoidal source term
```

? Thanks for any-and-all clarification/help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because *exponentials* are "eigenfunctions" of linear differential equations with constant coefficients. They spontaneously appear in homogenous equations and fit naturally in non-homogeneous ones.

The basic reason is the property

$$(e^{at})'=ae^{at}$$

telling that the derivative of an exponential is the same exponential, times a constant. When you plug that in a differential equation, say

$$y''(t)+Ay'(t)+By(t)=0,$$ you get the ordinary equation

$$(a^2+Aa+B)e^{at}=0$$

which is verified by the roots of the (so-called characteristic) polynomial.

In stable systems, the root(s) $a$ are negative real numbers or complex numbers with a negative real part. The function
$$e^{(-1/\tau+i\omega)t}=e^{-t/\tau}(\cos(\omega t)+i\sin(\omega t)),$$

is a sinusoid with exponential decay.

Now if you consider a sinusoidal RHS, let $Ce^{bt}$, you known that by plugging that function in the LHS you will get a similar exponential:

$$(b^2+Ab+B)e^{bt}=Ce^{bt}.$$

The solution is simply

$$\frac C{b^2+Ab+B}e^{bt}.$$

---

This property of the (complex) exponentials is so advantageous that a common resolution method is to decompose the RHS as a (possibly infinite) sum of exponentials, solve the equation for every component and recombine the partial solutions. This is the working principle of the Fourier/Laplace transform approach.

Comment: Thanks @Yves Daoust (+1)! I'm generally following your examples, more or less!  A few followup questions if you don't mind: **(a)** it sounds like my understanding that FT only applies to linear differential equations is correct - **can you please confirm that for me?** And **(b)** when you say that the number of decomposed components is possibly infinite, are there any factors that drive this? Meaning, are there specific factors that determine whether an RHS will decompose to a small number of components vs a large number? Thanks again!

Comment: Also **(c)** by "*...and recombine the partial solutions*", do you mean just adding the partial solutions together in a linear fashion?

Comment: The Fourier transform indeed essentially applies to linear equations *with constant coefficients*. In general, any function requires an infinite number of exponentials; nonperiodic functions take an uncountable number of them, while periodic functions take countably many (Fourier transform vs. Fourier series). Cases with a finite number of terms are the exception.

Comment: Linear systems enjoy the wonderful "superposition principle": the effect of a sum of causes is the same as the sum of the effect of the individual causes. This is what makes decomposition/recomposition possible.